# Bootstrap carousal minimum with min-height on small screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Bootstrap 4.4.1 framework with carousal on my page carousal has multiple images of 1920x250 pixels dimension which is fine for large screens, with smaller screen carousal image height also reduces and on phone it look too small,

I want to control height for different screens such a for iPhone(414 width) i want to keep banner height as minimum 200pixels height.

Can i control the height of the banner, in my code it maintains the aspect radio and banner is too small for small screen.

Example [link](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/vYNjqop)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cours Complet Bootstrap 4</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>

        <div id="carouselhp" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselhp" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselhp" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselhp" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x250.png?text=Some%20text%20will%20be%20placed%20on%20Banner1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x250.png?text=Some%20text%20will%20be%20placed%20on%20Banner2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x250.png?text=Some%20text%20will%20be%20placed%20on%20Banner3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselhp" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselhp" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you restrict the height, then the increased width would result in a horizontal scroll... and responsiveness is a lot about getting rid of horizontal scrolls

Comment: @AkberIqbal, not sure how they are doing it on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/ on this link height remain fixed

Comment: the images in the example have relatively similar ratios between height/width... compared to your image....